# How to see the element of particular index of 2D array in gdb?

Tags: c, gdb

```
char *str = "Coding";
char arr[5][10];

for (i = 0;i< 5; i++)
{
   for (j = 0; j< 10; j++)
   {
       if (i>=2 && j==0)
            {
                arr[i][j]= first_string[i-2];
            }
    }
}
```

Now I want to see the element at `arr[2][3]`.

When I do `p arr[2][3]`, it gives

> Cannot perform pointer math on incomplete types, try casting to a known type, or void *.

Comment: Are you sure you did that when the program was stopped in the scope of the variable?

Comment: What is `first_string`? Should that be `str`?

Answer (score 0):

Add a line to your program after the `for` loops

```
int main(void)
{
    ...
    return 0; // Line 20
}
```

Compile with `-g` (debug mode on)

```
gcc -std=c11 -Wall -g -o demo demo.c
```

Launch your program with gdb

```
gdb demo
```

set a breakpoint at line 20 (the line coresponding to `return 0;`)

```
break 20
```

run the program

```
run
```

print the value of the array

```
print arr[2][3]
```